# How to avoid friends' peer pressure to spend money on shopping & at restaurants?

Tags: cost-cutting, shopping, friends

How to avoid peer pressure from friends to spend money on shopping and at restaurants?

Answer (score 10):

- Realize that some friends are a bad influence, and maybe aren't really "friends".
- Don't be afraid to say "sorry, I can't make it tonight".  Don't be afraid to go out shopping and not buy anything.  Make sure they know why (Too much Credit Card Debit, saving for a house, etc).  If your habits suddenly change with no explanation, they may think you are dissing them.  But if you explain your reasons, they will probably support you (if they are *real* friends).  In fact, they probably have the same money issues.
- Suggest lower-cost alternatives to hanging out.  Instead of going out, suggest they come over to your place and watch a movie, play board games, Wii, etc.  You can have snacks at your place.  Alcohol is a lot cheaper when you pour it yourself!

Comment: +1 Alcohol is a lot cheaper when you pour it yourself!  BJ's has (had) a 24 pack of Sam Adams for roughly $24.  That's roughly a dollar a bottle. Compare that to the 3.50 you pay in any restaurant.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple strategies depending on the message you'd like to send. As far as shopping goes, you can:
Claim the spouse will kill you if you buy another X. This works for either gender. 
Say that you are saving for some expensive vacation or other item.
Go along but just seem lie nothing pleases you, be disinterested.

The restaurant thing is tougher, and you might want to just avoid it. Key thing is to say you'd like to get together but after lunch, you don't want the friend(s) to think you are avoiding them. Good luck!

Comment: It's particularly frustrating when you go to some expensive restaurant, and you order a salad because you really can't afford the place, and your friends say, "let's just split the bill evenly".

Comment: @Scott: True!  If one does get sucked into a restaurant with friends, one thing you can do - up front - is to ask the waiter to separate the bills.

Comment: I have tried to develop a tight wad reputation with my friends, so when I politely decline to split a bill evenly it won't be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Shopping is easy, I don't want to buy it, carry it around, store it in my home or wear it.  It is just an opinion about whatever the shopping is for.

When I don't want to spend the money on dining out, I just say I am broke and I will catch up next time.  Since they are my friends they understand and don't get too upset.  (like msemack says, if they get upset about it I don't think I would really care to spend time with them anyway)

While I am a big fan or eating at home and being cheap, I also recognize that my desire to spend money and have fun can't be suppressed for too long:  make a budget item for having fun and spend some of your money on a good time with your friends and family.

Make a date night with your spouse or friends and control when and where you go so your can control your budget.

Comment: +1 for entertainment budget - you don't have to be a monk. *Control* the spending.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the fun in going out to eat with friends is in the socializing.  So if you want to skip the overpriced appetizers+dinner+drinks but don't want to miss the fun, you can always just do the "oh I already ate, but I'll come along and just hang out/have a drink/snack/dessert!"

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to not participate in the expensive habits at all.  Try to direct your friends to cheaper venues.

- Rent movies and watch at home instead of going to the movies.
- Cook at home and invite friend (though this can get out of hand too.
- Play games.  Ten adults playing capture the flag can still be fun.

It's important to note that some hobbies are a large investment.  Shooting sports, model airplanes, and customizing vehicles are all examples of hobbies you might want to avoid when you're on a budget.

Comment: The difference between eating out and entertaining in is at least 4 or 5 to 1. As mentioned above, beer, $4 or $5 in a restaurant/bar, and the food, it's not tough to exceed $30/head. 
With the right group of people, doing the home invites can be great. Burgers, Dogs, and Chicken on the grill, and a case of beer and that per head price drops like a rock.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Yes if you do it right.  I've seen people go crazy at home preparing a dinner.  It also doesn't work if people don't share the cost (either by rotating homes or chipping in).